# How to save date/time with Django form

Tags: django

When I submit a form, the POST request data is shown as ridetime_year,ridetime_day, and ridetime_month.

How I capture the date/time from my form and save it to the DB? Thanks

Forms.py

```
class AddRideSpot(forms.Form):

    ridetime = forms.DateTimeField(widget=SelectDateWidget,initial=datetime.date.today())

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data

        ridetime = cleaned_data.get("ridetime")
        return cleaned_data
```

views.py

```
def add_point(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.AddRideSpot(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            cd = form.cleaned_data

            new_ride = models.Ride()

            new_ride.ridetime = cd['ridetime']

            new_ride.save()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, when you submit the form, you will get the value for `ridetime` in `cleaned_data` as an `datetime` object which will look like this `2014-11-18 00:00:00`. You can save that object directly to model if your model field is `DateTimeField`. The way you are saving the value of `ridetime` in views.py should work fine.

So using `SelectDateWidget` will only get you the date when you submit the form. If you want to save the datetime, you can try like this (using [DateTimeInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#datetimeinput)):

```
ridetime = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'], widget=forms.DateTimeInput(format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
```

It will render a TextField where you need to input the date in the format mentioned above(example: `18/11/2014 12:12:00`). You can use JQuery like [DateTimePicker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) to select datetime on that text field. The DateTimeInput Widget will give you a datetime object which contains your inputted date/time. So you can save it directly in the models.

Comment: You actually solved 2 problems, because I couldn't figure out how to capture Time in addition to the calendar day. So when I submit the form, is it normal to see the values for year, month, day, etc in the headers? Does it then get compiled as an object ?

Comment: Well rendering seperate fields for year,month,day is the task of SelectDateWidget. Saving it isn't complicated because you will get a datetime object in cleaned data while using SelectDateWidget.

Comment: I'm still getting an error with your suggested changes. It says: Exception Type: IntegrityError at /bike/add_point/
Exception Value: null value in column "ridetime" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (10, , null, , , 10).

Comment: I think you need to change the model field like: ridetime= models.DateTimeField(null=True)

Comment: well null=True seemed to fix things, no idea why...THANKS!