# Django bound form is invalid but not ValidationError raised

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

I have a problem in my Django form. When I click the submit button in my form, no data is saved to the database. I found that the data was **bound** but it did not pass through the `form.is_valid()` function. Below is the code for `forms.py`, `views.py`, `urls.py` and `new-event.html` respectively:
`forms.py`

```
from django import forms
class EventForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='event-name',
                           max_length=50,
                           widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'event-name', 'name': 'event-name'}))

    start_datetime = forms.DateTimeField(
    widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'start-datetime', 'name': 'start-datetime', 'type': 'datetime-local'}))

    end_datetime = forms.DateTimeField(
    widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'end-datetime', 'name': 'end-datetime', 'type': 'datetime-local'}))

    event_category = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'custom-select', 'id': 'event-type'}),
    choices=((None, 'Please select an option'), ('Daily Life', 'Daily Life'), ('Study', 'Study'), ('Social', 'Social'), ('Work', 'Work')))

    description = forms.CharField(max_length=250, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'description', 'name': 'description'}), required=False)
```

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Entry
from .forms import EventForm
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST

# request is required that represents HttpResponse
# return value can be response, JSON or template

def index(request):
    entries = Entry.objects.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'entries': entries}
    return render(request, 'event/list-events.html', context)

def new_event(request):
    form = EventForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'event/new-event.html', context)

@require_POST
def add_event(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = EventForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_bound: print('form is bound')
        else: print('form is unbound')

        if form.is_valid():
            print('form is valid')
            new_entry = Entry(name=form.cleaned_data['name'], start_datetime=form.cleaned_data['start_datetime'],
                              end_datetime=form.cleaned_data['end_datetime'], category=form.cleaned_data['event_category'],
                              description=form.cleaned_data['description'])
            new_entry.save()

        else:
            print('form is invalid')
            return render(request, 'event/new-event.html', {'form': form})

        return redirect('index')

    # else:
    #     form = EventForm()
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('new-event/', views.new_event, name='new_event'),
    path('add-event/', views.add_event, name='add_event')
]
```

`new-event.html`

```
{% extends 'todo/base.html' %}

{% block title %}New Entry{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <form action="{% url 'add_event' %}" method="POST" class="container-fluid">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="event-name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Event</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                {{ form.name }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="event-type" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Event type</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                {{ form.event_category }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="start-datetime" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Start Time</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                {{ form.start_datetime }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="end-datetime" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">End Time</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                {{ form.end_datetime }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.description }}
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

The output on my terminal is: `form is bound form is invalid`... I am sure that I do not fall into the confusion of concepts between *bound* and *instance*. Could anyone give me some tips on how this occurs?

Comment: Finally, I found the cause of not being able to successfully save data to database. The reason is `start_datetime` and `end_datetime` are specified as `input type=datetime_local`, which is not fully supported in the current version of Django, as opposed to the default type `input type=text`. See [Django form.DateTimeInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.DateTimeInput). Thank you @Daniel Roseman for your kind help :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you think that this is a problem. Your form was correctly bound to the POST data; then, that data was validated, and found not to pass the validation.

To see why - and allow the user to correct the issue - you should output `{{ form.errors }}` on your template, or use the individual errors attributes for each field, eg `{{ form.name.errors }}` etc.

Comment: Please forgive me if I'm asking a stupid question, since I'm new to Django. Do you mean the POST data has been validated so it fails in the form.is_valid() condition?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure what's is confusing you.

Comment: Okay. The problem I currently have is I cannot get the `start_datetime` and `end_datetime` fields from `form.cleaned_data` dictionary as they are not included after being cleaned. This is what I read from [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/#ref-forms-api-bound-unbound): 'If your data does not validate, the cleaned_data dictionary contains only the valid fields:' I also checked if the raw data contains both date values and it does. How do I access both date values from `cleaned_data` then?

Comment: Well, again, they're not there because the fields aren't valid, and `form.errors` will tell you why.

Comment: Printing `form.errors` shows this: `<ul class="errorlist"><li>start_datetime<ul class="errorlist"><li>Enter a valid date/time.</li></ul></li><li>end_datetime<ul class="errorlist"><li>Enter a valid date/time.</li></ul></li></ul>`. Someone had a same situation and the answer to the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985157/how-to-save-date-time-with-django-form) was specifying `input_formats` in `DateTimeField` in `forms.py`. I followed but the same error message still shows up.